# Solr lucene schema.xml multi-valued entries, please help

Tags: java, lucene, solr, schema, indexing

Essentially I am trying to link a user type to a price for a product.

So a product is a document in the index, and each document has multiple prices, one for each user type.

And i am essentially trying to check the price for that usertype

e.g. where user type = 2 and price > 10

But each product can have a varying number of different user types each with an individual price.

I need a way to say user type = x and that user types price > 10

I am using solr version 1.4.1 and cant seem to see a way to create a field that works in this way.

As i am writing a schema.xml file for this document so I dont have the option to create individual fields for each usertype I need a universal solution for however many user types I that are required.

thanks in advance google and bing have given me nothing and im banging my head against a wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... One thing you could try is using [dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) in solr to solve this problem.

As you add fields you just name them like price_usertypex_i (see some examples in the schema.xml as well). As you add user types you create more fields, but you don't have to modify your schema because it is dynamic.

One caveat is that I don't think you'd be able to use dataimporthandler in this scenario, since I don't think it works with dynamic fields (you'd have to roll your own import).

Comment: this might be what im looking for, will try and get back to you, fingers crossed!

Comment: Thankyou this solves my problem, I didnt know you could create dynamic fields on the fly!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have the right data model but with the constraints you are describing, you could index the prod description and append to it a separator and the U1 123 U12 154

where user 1 price is 123 dollars and user12 is 154 dollars ? This would allow you to search by user. The price interval would have to be post-processed.

The more standard way would be to add a column "price" per user

Comment: the main problem with this approach is it requires me to retreive the entire data set in order to sort or do price range queries, so computationaly expensive

Comment: Actually do you need full text search ? If you do you can add a product ID column and put all your users and prices in MySQL. If there are too many text search results with Solr that need to be processed, then use Lucene + MySQL. Don't know if you can get what you want with facets and different columns

Comment: yeah unfortunately I do. I already have my data in mysql but the search and mysql fulltext search is not good enough for the clients requrements. I was thinking something in facets could help me but its the linking of the two bits of data. If i was doing an exact match with price I could do it in a standard text column, but as I need to do range queries im stuck.

Comment: I don't see any other solution than --- yourfulltext:word AND price_u1:[15 TO 25.5] ---

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to SOLR, but what I'd do is create a different document per each combo product/userType. Yes, you'd have several documents for the same product, but from what I can see so far the server handles it pretty well.

...

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: that was my backup approach if i could not find a way to include it in a single document. I'd rather avoid it as it would increase my index by however many user types i have. My client has 50,000 products and 50 user types so its within the performance range of lucene, but not ideal should that increase in the future.

Comment: Seems like a valid concern. Well, if you ever get a better approach please do share with the rest of us people. =) Thank you!